# Tabulator - Multiple custom filter implementation in React JS app

Tags: reactjs, filter, tabulator

I have a react app and have implemented Tabuator as data grid library.

But need to have multple custom filters like as image [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wODk.png).

I can see that there is jquery example when I search multiple filters in documentation, but need in react js.

Do ReactTabulator component have any props for the above situation ?

TIA,
Sid

Comment: there's already an implementation here `https://codesandbox.io/s/0mwpy612xw`. This uses `react-tabualator` package

Comment: Yes, it has but not for the multiple filter options.